# Show a splash image when redirection to login page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a site on Azure website. Sometime it takes several seconds when redirecting to the login page. And the screen shows a blank page and users are complaining. Is it a way to show some splash page while it's loading the login page?
[image]

Comment: It could be that the app pool is not active, do you have "Always on" enabled for the website?

Comment: I was told the Azure setting already has "Always on" enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of an animate gif saying loading or stuff like that. what you need to do is that place that Gif in a div. Hide the div initially and make it visible once you click the login button or link like this:

```
<script>
  $('#loader').show();<--this makes the Gif visible while you are redirecting to login page-->
</script>
<html>
<body>

<div id="loader" style="display:none"><img src="~/Content/loading1.gif" /></div><--div with the hidden gif image-->
<div id="mainDiv"><--the div with you main content of the page-->
<--this can be a login button or action link-->
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Save" formmethod="post" onclick="showGif()" />
 <--rest of your code-->
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: There is no clicking in my case. The index.cshtml page automatically redirect to login page when it's not logged.